# How repeat sound of local notification until any button of alert view is not pressed?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uialertview, nssound

I have an alarm clock in which i have set a local notification on user set data. Now when local notification generate then an alert view appear and a sound also played. But sound play for 2 seconds while i required that while not pressed any button of alert view till sound play. For example local notification appear at 11:15 AM and  alert view show message with two buttons. One is close and second is view. And a background music also played. But music play for 2-3 seconds and stop. I required that sound will not stop until user not pressed any button. How do that event?

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In local notification sound of alert will play for 30 seconds by default. So we can not manage it customize.